# UITableView numberOfRowsInSection works fine on IOS8 but has weird behaviour on IOS7

Tags: objective-c

I created an app for both IOS8 and IOS7 but I found a problem, I store on a sqlite DB some info that I need to show when the user opens a certain UIViewController that contains a UITableView. The problem is that when the user enters the UIViewController the tableView method gets fired:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return numProdotti; //this is the number of rows in my local DB, initially is 0
}
```

the I calculate the number of rows in my DB and on IOS8 the `numberOfRowsInSection` gets fired again, but on IOS7 it doesn't, so I just get an empty UITableView.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should calculate your number of rows in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Obviously i'm calculating it on the viewDidLoad, but the numberOfRowsInSection gets called before it

Comment: Just call reloadData on the tableView after calculating the number of rows.

Comment: yeah thank you, calling reloadData worked. But still I don't understand why there's this kind of difference from IOS7 to IOS8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` will calculate the rows on the `viewDidLoad` method. This happens before you get a chance to do your own calculations. Therefore, once you have them, you need to call `reloadData` as suggested in the comments section. Odd and very slight behaviour change between iOS7 and 8.